# Texas holdem straight check values

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm have a small issue with evaluating a straight in a seven card hand, where you want to get the highest 5 card straight.

I can get highest 5 card straight as long as there is not a pair in the hand so for example:

Hole cards: 2h,3d
community cards:4h, 5s, 6s, 8d, 9d,
Output: 2h,3d,4h,5s,6s

Because there is no pair within the straight it counts and outputs just fine.
The problem occurs when there is a pair within the straight
for example:

Hole cards: 2h, 3d,
community cards: 4h, 4c, 5s, 6s, 8d
Output: 2h,3d,4h,4c,5s

So it is counting the pair in the straight, I need a way to skip past one of the paired cards and select only one. This happens with 3 of a kind as well.

It makes complete sense to me why it is doing this, but for the life of me I can't think of a way to fix it.

Here is the function:

```
bool Player::checkForStraight()
{
//Loops through the ranks from greatest to least 0 is NONE is the enum class
for (int i = FACES; i >= 1; i--)
{
    //Checks to see if a straight exists (_checkNumfaces is an array[13] to
    //hold the amount of each card
    if ((_checkNumFaces[i - 1] >= 1) && (_checkNumFaces[i - 2] >= 1) &&
        (_checkNumFaces[i - 3] >= 1) && (_checkNumFaces[i - 4] >= 1) &&
        (_checkNumFaces[i - 5] >= 1))
    {
        //If a straight exists loop through the cards(sorted in another 
        //function from lowest to highest
        for (int j = 6; j >= 0; j--)
        {
                //if the face matches the enum value of i then we have a
                //straight there down because I checked if the straight
                //existed already
                if ((*p_playerHand[j])->face == (Face)(i))
                {
                    //PlayerHighCards out of the seven
                    p_playerHighFive[4] = p_playerHand[j];
                    p_playerHighFive[3] = p_playerHand[j - 1];
                    p_playerHighFive[2] = p_playerHand[j - 2];
                    p_playerHighFive[1] = p_playerHand[j - 3];
                    p_playerHighFive[0] = p_playerHand[j - 4];
                    return true;
                }
            }
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Sorry about the shoddy formatting at the bottom but its only curly braces and they are fine in my code.

I know how to check for A,2,3,4,5 straight I just havnt coded yet, I am just really stumped on how to move past one of the pairs that I was on about. Its not just pairs, this occurs with 3 of a kind as well (so if there's 3 of a kind in the straight) or more than one pair for that matter so 2 pairs. Doesn't happen outside of this because there's not physically enough cards to be concerned about it.

Sorry if my code is not that elegant and if there's a better way then let me know. I havnt learned templates or the stl yet as I have only just started the language so a solution not using these would be great.

I tried to be as descriptive as possible but, I'm new to this so if you have any questions just ask:)

Here is the function for counting the different cards in the deck

```
    void Player::countNumFaces(const int& size)
{

for (int i = 0; i < (size); i++)
{
    switch((*p_playerHand[i])->face)
    {
    case Face::NONE:    std::cout << "Joker" << std::endl;
    case Face::TWO:     _checkNumFaces[0]  ++;  break;
    case Face::THREE:   _checkNumFaces[1]  ++;  break;
    case Face::FOUR:    _checkNumFaces[2]  ++;  break;
    case Face::FIVE:    _checkNumFaces[3]  ++;  break;
    case Face::SIX:     _checkNumFaces[4]  ++;  break;
    case Face::SEVEN:   _checkNumFaces[5]  ++;  break;
    case Face::EIGHT:   _checkNumFaces[6]  ++;  break;
    case Face::NINE:    _checkNumFaces[7]  ++;  break;
    case Face::TEN:     _checkNumFaces[8]  ++;  break;
    case Face::JACK:    _checkNumFaces[9]  ++;  break;
    case Face::QUEEN:   _checkNumFaces[10] ++;  break;
    case Face::KING:    _checkNumFaces[11] ++;  break;
    case Face::ACE:     _checkNumFaces[12] ++;  break;
    }
}

std::cout << "| 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6 || 7 || 8 || 9 | 10 || J || Q || K || A |" << std::endl;      //Print for testing
for (int i = 0; i < FACES; i++) { std::cout << "| " << _checkNumFaces[i] << " |"; }                  //Print for testing
}
```

Comment: You are checking too many cards.  You only need card + 4 previous.

Comment: How do you mean sorry? I am checking for 5 cards, where am I checking to many? The bug im talking about has nothing to do with checking to many cards though.

Comment: hold on ill put the other function up to make it more clear whats going on

Comment: The reason it is doing it is because my if statement  with _checkNumFaces[i - any of above] >= 1 is evaluating to true with pairs in the hand(this is what I want). If I where to put _checkNumFaces[i - 1] == 1 it would stop the behavior but I would not be catching all of the straights as in a seven card hand you can have pairs, two pairs and trips as well as a straight.

Comment: every statement I have tried to correct this has come up as a dead end, i.e. running another loop inside to push past the card, an if else statement to do one value if this occurs or another if it doesn't. These haven't worked for me and I'm a bit stumped as the pair or trips or whatever can occur anywhere within the 5 card straight.

Comment: Oh yeah and Im only checking one card Stark as I check for the straight with the _checkNumFaces array and if my last card position is equal to( i ) then all the cards below it in descending order are a straight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
p_playerHighFive[4] = p_playerHand[j];
p_playerHighFive[3] = p_playerHand[j - 1];
p_playerHighFive[2] = p_playerHand[j - 2];
p_playerHighFive[1] = p_playerHand[j - 3];
p_playerHighFive[0] = p_playerHand[j - 4];
return true;
```

try

```
int k = 4;
int l = 0;

p_playerHighFive[k] = p_playerHand[j-l]; 
k--;
l++;

while(k>=0)
{
    if( isSameValue(p_playerHighFive[k+1], p_playerHand[j-l]) ) //check if card has same value
    {
        l++;
        continue;
    }

    p_playerHighFive[k] = p_playerHand[j-l];
    k--;
    l++;

}
```

Comment: I take that back it takes care of all of it :) perfect thanks :)

Comment: PS2. You should be absolutely sure that you have straight because if not it will blow you in the face as I don't check if j-l>=0.

Comment: Yeah the if statement above takes care of it...ran about 300 iterations and it captures them with pairs in there etc. Thanks alot for that I was realy stuck!

Comment: I have upvoted, it just doesn't show because i have less than 15 posts or whatever.

Comment: Hmm. found the problem that you were hinting at. When you get a situation when where the straight starts from 4 and there is no Ace at the top it runs of the beginning of the Array and evaluates to true and crashes because any old garbage in there will evaluate to >= 1(at least I think, Gonna try figure this one out I will post back if I get to stuck.

Comment: you can do it like this: add this before while `int  sizeOfPlayerHand = ...; // probably 7` and change inside while both `[j-l]` to [(j-l<0)?sizeOfPlayerHand+j-l:j-l]` or even better to `[(sizeOfPlayerHand+j-l)%sizeOfPlayerHand]`

Comment: Wow, it took me a while to understand what you did there. Thanks for your help Logman

Comment: FLUSHES WHERE A BREEZE LOL

Comment: I'm glad I could help.